# Does a small amount of fusion occur in the explosion of atomic bombs?

Tags: atomic-physics

Because of the amount of heat and pressure produced, is it possible that as a side effect of convention fission weapons, a small amount of atoms are fused?

Answer (score 0):

To get fusion to occur in a fission bomb, fusion fuel (for example, lithium deuteride) must be present inside the fission fuel. Since fusible materials aren't in the list of fission bomb components, it is unlikely that there will be appreciable amounts of fusion reactions occurring when a conventional fission bomb goes off.

However, it is possible to increase the yield of a fission bomb by incorporating some fusion fuel in it on purpose- to produce what is called a *boosted fission bomb*. In this case, the purpose of adding the fusion fuel is to greatly increase the neutron flux through the fissionable material at the instant of explosion, thereby getting more of it to fission before the exploding critical mass blows itself far enough apart to quench the fission chain reaction.

Comment: My question is would *any* fusion occur? Would any elements at all be produced because very energetic atoms of the same or even two different elements got pushed into each other? Not concerned about energy being produced by fusion but whether atoms get fused or if there is some reason that this can't happen even in the high-energy zone near the center of the explosion.

Comment: probably not. The constituents of the bomb have atomic weights too high for energy release by fusion.

Comment: What about air inside? The LA-602 report considered nitrogen-nitrogen fusion.

Comment: Note that lithium deuteride is only useful in the secondary, not the primary. You need neutrons from the primary to convert the lithium to tritium.

Comment: @nielsnielsen: is there fusion without energy release?